# Many switch cases but 1 activity

Tags: android, android-intent

First of all there are few buttons.

I am set a switch case for all buttons in onClick method.

I want to do different task for all buttons like e.g

For add button I want to display questions of Addition , same for subtraction etc.

But I want to start same activity on the click of the buttons, I mean I have a counter class which should start before the actual questions starts getting displayed.

So on the click on any of the buttons I want to start that counter activity an after that display the questions.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent Counter = new Intent(this, TYS_Counter.class);
    startActivity(Counter);

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.BAddition:

        break;
    case R.id.BSubtraction:

        break;
    case R.id.BMultiplication:

        break;
    case R.id.BDivision:

        break;
    case R.id.BAll:

        break;
    }

}
```

I have done this , is this correct or not, I dont think so, so please guide me.

Edit:

I want when the user clicks on any button the the timer of 3 2 1 starts and when it finishes then the activity with questions starts.

Thanks

Comment: You need to be a little more clear on your actual question. Does it work as you expect? If not, how or how not? If it does then you have done it correctly. Are you expecting the first `Activity` to show the question after the timer expires?

Comment: Edited @above and added more details please check it.

Comment: I have posted an answer. If I understand what you want then the second option should work for you but it depends on how you are showing the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I think you are saying, you want to display the question after the timer expires. You have several options. One is that you can use

```
Intent Counter = new Intent(this, TYS_Counter.class);
startActivityForResult(Counter);  // notice the change here
```

Then when your timer `Activity` finishes, it can use `setResult()` and return a value to `onActivityResult()` you can then start the `Activity` with the questions you want depending on what is sent back from the timer `Activity`.

If you want to start a new `Activity` when the counter expires then you could change your code like this

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent Counter = new Intent(this, TYS_Counter.class);

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.BAddition:
        counter.putExtra("key", "addition");
        break;
    case R.id.BSubtraction:
        counter.putExtra("key", "subtraction");
        break;
    case R.id.BMultiplication:
        counter.putExtra("key", "multiplication");
        break;
    case R.id.BDivision:
        counter.putExtra("key", "division");
        break;
    case R.id.BAll:
        counter.putExtra("key", "whateverThisIs");
        break;
    }
startActivity(Counter);

}
```

Then when your counter `Activity` finishes you can use the extra sent to tell it which `Activity` to start

Comment: Ok so basically we have to use counters intent with buttons switch case??

This was the only thing which I was not getting..
Rest its already 4:25 am so sleepy now...Will try this code and if will face any problem then will let you know, hope you dont have any problem with that.

Thanks

Comment: As I said, it depends exactly how you display your questions (separate Activities, etc...) but something like this should work. Get some sleep, I may be sleeping when you check it as its 6:55 p.m. here but go ahead and ask if you run into a problem. You may need to tweak this code a little but it should get you going. Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot of your support and patience...
Actually I dont have anyone helping me personally so facing a lot of problems as I am a novice user till now.

Comment: No problem. The SO community is a great place to get help as long as you respect the rules such as asking precise questions, showing effort, posting relevant code and error messages, and contribute

Comment: Yeah but dont know why I always get scared while posting on SO, maybe because of losing reputation points, many times I ask relevant questions even then the users rate it negative :(

Comment: It happens. There are some people that don't treat the system with respect and people that have different views. Don't be scared. Just post it and if it is a valid question/answer, you will get the rep you deserve in the end plus you will learn